# My newsletter is too big because of base64 images

Tags: html, image, base64, newsletter

I created an html newsletter.  The images are optimized and loaded to the server.  I use a link to show the images on the html newsletter.

When I upload the newsletter to acumbamail it gives me an error saying that the newsletter is too big and I have base64 images.

The file is 19kbs in size.  How do I deal with base64 images?

[Here is the corresponding codepen](https://codepen.io/shinotenshi9192/pen/aymPwZ).

Here is the corresponding HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>¿Listo para ver nuestros productos de la semana?</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
 {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

table, td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}

</style>
<style type="text/css">
.button-td, .button-a {
    transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}
.button-td:hover, .button-a:hover {
    background: #555555 !important;
    border-color: #555555 !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#2A2A2A" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#2A2A2A" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td><center style="width: 100%;">
      <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">¿Listo para ver nuestros productos de la semana?</div>
<div style="max-width: 600px;"> 
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr style="background-color: white;">
              <td style="padding: 8px 0; text-align: center"><img src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/logo.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="alt_text" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color: white;"><td><p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center;"><i>Newsletter nº 223• Echa un vistazo a nuestro nuevo producto!</i></p></td></tr>

          </table>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <br>
            <tr>
              <td class="full-width-image" align="center" ><a href="http://www.camaras-espias.com/94-minicamara-mas-pequena-del-mundo-que-graba-en-alta-definicion.html"><img src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/newproduct.png" width="100%" height="auto"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"><h1 style="text-align: center;">
                    Minicámara mas pequeña del mundo
                    </h1>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center;">149,90 €</h3>
                    ¡nadie percibirá su presencia. Puede grabar sonido y posee visión nocturna invisible que se activará de manera automática cuando detecte que hay poca luz, tiene tantas ventajas, que hace imposible que no desees una para tu trabajo. ¿Te parece irresistible? Pues tenemos una esperándote. <br>
                    <br>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #32C74B; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.camaras-espias.com/94-minicamara-mas-pequena-del-mundo-que-graba-en-alta-definicion.html" style="background: #32C74B; border: 15px solid #32C74B; padding: 0 10px;color: black; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> ¡Lo quiero! </a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="full-width-image" align="center" ><a href="http://www.camaras-espias.com/817-marco-de-fotos-espia.html"><img src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/banner.jpg" width="600" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"><h1 style="text-align: center;">
                    Marco de fotos espía
                    </h1>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center;">83,94 €</h3>
                    Los objetos espías se han convertido cada vez en más ocultos y es que en esta ocasión te traemos un marco de fotos tradicional, donde podrás colocar una foto tuya, de tus familiares o de quien tu quieras y además estar grabando tanto de forma continua como por detección de movimiento, tanto imagen como sonido, ¿no es espectacular? ¡Por un tiempo limitado el precio se ha reducido! ¡Consiga el suyo ahora! ¿Recuerda quién sospecharía que un marco de fotos los está grabando? <br>
                    <br>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #32C74B; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.camaras-espias.com/817-marco-de-fotos-espia.html" style="background: #32C74B; border: 15px solid #32C74B; padding: 0 10px;color: black; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> ¡Lo quiero! </a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">
                                ¿Tienes alguna duda?<br>
                <span>Por favor pregúntanos y estaremos encantados de responderte</span> <br>
                <br>

                <button type="button" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; background-color:#32C74B; border-radius: 10px; "><a href="mailto:info@camaras-espias.com" style="color: white; font-size:18px; text-decoration: none;">info@camaras-espias.com</a></button>
                </td>
            </tr>            
            <tr> <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; text-align:center;">
     <p><a style="color: #32C74B; font-weight: bold;" href="http://acumbamail.com/url/ver/22290138/" target="_blank">www.camaras-espias.com</a> · Teléfono <a style="color: #32C74B; font-weight: bold;">966 410 611</a></p>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>

                                          <tr>
                                <td>
                              <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding:0; text-align: center;">               
                              <li style="display: inline;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/camarasespia"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/facebook.png" width="512" height="512" alt="facebook"/></a></li>
                              <li style="display: inline;"><a href="https://plus.google.com/+CamarasEspiasTienda"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/google-plus.png" width="512" height="512" alt="google+"/></a></li>
                              <li style="display: inline;"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/camarasespias/"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/pinterest.png" width="512" height="512" alt="pinterest"/></a></li>
                              <li style="display: inline;"><a href="https://twitter.com/CamarasEspias"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/twitter.png" width="512" height="512" alt="twitter"/></a></li>
                              <li style="display: inline;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/containfo09"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://camaras-espias.com/newsletters/20170801/youtube.png" width="512" height="512" alt="youtube"/></a></li>
                              </ul></td>
                              </tr>

              <tr><td style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;"> <p><a style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" href="*|UNSUBSCRIBE_URL|*">Cancelar la suscripción</a> <a style=" color: white; text-decoration: none;" href="*|BROWSER_VIEW|*">Ver en el navegador</a></p></td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was testing it and it got posted -_-  either way, check out the link, please.  I appreciate your feedback

Comment: @john-philip  thanks for the edits

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO by the way. If you need help for your further edits or questions do not hesitate to refer to the appropriate documentation which is quite well done.